# Un-ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. A clarification on the construction

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I'm following the proof given in Koblitz's book which roughly speaking builds the un-ramified extension of degree $f$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as $\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of the lift of the minimal polynomial of a primitive root in $\mathbb{F}_{p^f}$.

Can we assume that $\alpha$ is an integral unit?

I think yes, and my idea is to use symmetricity of the minimal polynomial of a primitive root in $\mathbb{F}_{p^f}$, which I think can be preserved after the lifting, (hence $\alpha^{-1}$ is an integer and therefore is a unit) but being these my firsts steps in this field (pun intended) I need some guidance and opinion.

Comment: $\alpha$ will be a root unity so, yes, it is integral. Besides, won't Hensel lifting of an irreducible factor over $\Bbb{F}_p$ produce a monic polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: Well, when you say 'the lift of the minimal polynomial', you really mean '*a* lift of the minimal polynomial'. If you choose the cyclotomic polynomial as the lift of the cyclotomic polynomial, then $\alpha$ will be a root of unity, as Jyrki mentioned. Since you get to choose the lift, this should answer your question.

Comment: yes, clear. thank you very much!